# Wordpress adds a number into url on a script page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a script called search.php that uses some search engines API`s and renders the results.

I've made from this file a Page template, and I'm using this [simplePagination plugin](http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/)

The tricky part is that when I click on any page from that pagination, the pages first takes me to 
mylink.is/search/2/?query=text&page=1 , and afterwards takes me to page=2,3..etc.

[HERE IS THE WEBSITE PAGE](http://peepus.is/search/)

Why is that "2" after my search page? How can I remove it?

Answer (score 2):

This is a "GET" variable, it's one of the methods used by PHP to keep track of what data your user has submitted from their browser - in this case, the text to search for, and the portion of the results to return. This information is needed for search.php to output the proper HTML, the code that reflects what the user is looking for.

It helps to remember that there may be three pages of results, but only one search.php - these GET variables alter the behaviour of the code it runs.

Try adding this parameter to your paginate_links function:

```
'format' => '/page/%#%',
```

For more information:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links

Hope I helped!
[Edit: I actually mixed up POST and GET, this is a GET]

Comment: But I don't use paginate_links, I'm using that js script in the link aboce. I just don't understand how could I fix this.